# Pandas combine strings with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to combine strings in my data frame. The dataframe looks like:

```
0          code   text1
1        507489   text2
2        507489   text3
3        506141   text4
4        506141   text5
5        504273   text6
```

My current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("location.csv", header=None, delimiter=';', dtype='unicode', nrows=100)
new_header = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:] 
df.columns = new_header

df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index()

df.to_csv (r'new_location\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)
print(df)
```

But I am not getting the expected results. The output looks the same as the input while I was expecting:

```
0          code   text1
1        507489   text2->text3
2        506141   text4->text5
3        504273   text6
```

Quite new to this so I must be making some easy mistake.

Dataframe that produces same result:

```
testf = {'code': ['1','2','2','4'],
        'text': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(testf, columns = ['code', 'text'])
```

Comment: hi , please add `DF` that will can run , don't forget we don't have your csv, and that will make time to implement you `DF`  you have to follow this step before https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added a df that produces the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you forget assign back, also was removed `header=None` in `read_csv` because in file is header used for columns names in DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("location.csv", sep=';', dtype='unicode', nrows=100)

df = df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index()
print (df)
     code         text1
0  504273         text6
1  506141  text4->text5
2  507489  text2->text3

df.to_csv (r'new_location\export_dataframe.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Tried this but still producing the same result.

Comment: @Elmer - Solution was simplify, can you test?

Comment: Removed header=None but still doesn't work. How do do you mean forgot assign back? The .reset.index()?

Comment: @Elmer - I think `df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index()` vs `df = df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index()`

Comment: Solved. It was indeed df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index() vs df = df.groupby('code').agg('->'.join).reset_index()